# Docker image dotnet-framework 4.7.2-sdk missing SDK files

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-for-windows

I am seeing weird behavior with docker build image outputs. 
When I build a docker image from my dockerfile on Windows 2016 server machine (M1), the output image is fine and as expected. However, if I try the same procedure on a different machine (M2), some crucial files are missing. I don't see any errors of any sort when building images. Both M1 and M2 are same Win2016 Datacenter OS. M2 is domain joined but M1 is not.

My dockerfile is like this:

```
# escape=`
FROM microsoft/dotnet-framework:4.7.2-sdk
RUN mkdir c:\install
ADD WebDeploy_amd64_en-US.msi c:\install\WebDeploy_amd64_en-US.msi
WORKDIR c:\install
RUN powershell start-Process msiexec.exe -ArgumentList "/i","c:\install\WebDeploy_amd64_en-US.msi","/qn" -Wait
ADD https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/vs_buildtools.exe C:\install\vs_buildtools.exe
SHELL ["cmd", "/S", "/C"]
RUN C:\install\vs_buildtools.exe --quiet --wait --norestart --nocache `
    --installPath C:\BuildTools `
    --add Microsoft.Net.Component.4.7.1.SDK `
 || IF "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="3010" EXIT 0


RUN mkdir c:\install\sxs
ADD microsoft-windows-netfx3-ondemand-package.cab c:\install\sxs\microsoft-windows-netfx3-ondemand-package.cab
WORKDIR c:\install
RUN powershell Install-WindowsFeature -Name NET-Framework-Features -Source C:\install\sxs -Verbose
CMD ["powershell.exe", "-NoLogo", "-ExecutionPolicy", "Bypass"]
```

Contents of C:\Program Files (x86) from container running on M2:

- Common Files
- IIS
- internet explorer
- Microsoft Visual Studio
- Microsoft.NET
- MSBuild
- Reference Assemblies
- Windows Defender
- WindowsPowerShell

Contents of C:\Program Files (x86) from container running on M1:

- Common Files
- IIS
- internet explorer
- **Microsoft SDKs**
- Microsoft Visual Studio
- Microsoft.NET
- MSBuild
- Reference Assemblies
- Windows Defender
- **Windows Kits**
- WindowsPowerShell

Same command used to build images on M1 and M2:

```
docker build -t vsbuildtools -m 2GB .
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are both machines have the same underlying base OS? Both LTSC Windows 2016 and not SAC channel?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Well installation of sdk fails and you don't see error since you are running in silent mode. You need to modify statement to output everything to stdout.

Comment: I replaced it with 

` RUN C:\install\vs_buildtools.exe --quiet --wait --norestart --nocache `
    --installPath C:\BuildTools `
    --add Microsoft.Net.Component.4.7.1.SDK > install.log` 
 || IF "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="3010" EXIT 0 `

But no errors in install.log

Comment: Try to remove --quiet

Comment: I tried that too but it hangs. I mean docker build doesn't move past that statement.

Comment: Ok so your issue is very narrow right and question needs to be updated. You are unable to run vs_buildtools.exe inside windows container, it either does not start or  start and hangs

Comment: See if below is sufficient to show the issue
# escape=`
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore
RUN MKDIR c:\install
ADD https://aka.ms/vs/15/release/vs_buildtools.exe C:\install\vs_buildtools.exe
RUN C:\install\vs_buildtools.exe --quiet --wait --norestart --nocache --installPath C:\BuildTools --add Microsoft.Net.Component.4.7.1.SDK

Comment: Don't you think that it's expected? As per the docs, the **--quiet** flag - _Do not display any user interface while performing the installation_. 

And this image is based off Windows Server Core hence, in my opinion, its expected.

Comment: Correct, I was not sure what it does. I run sample manually and was able to successfully build on 1803 and ltst2016 images. I can also see that even with --quiet flag it still outputs data to stdout. So use mysample above and see if it installs buildtools successfully or not, so reproduction steps will be very concise

Comment: I tried your sample but build operation fails. Error

`The command 'cmd /S /C C:\install\vs_buildtools.exe --quiet --wait --norestart --nocache --installPath C:\BuildTools --add Microsoft.Net.Component.4.7.1.SDK' returned a non-zero code: 2147483697`

Comment: On both of your servers?

Comment: It works on M1 but not on M2. It's strange! Here are their details:

M1 - Windows Server 2016 Datacenter. Version: 1607. OS Build: 14393.2248
M2 - Windows Server 2016 Datacenter. Version: 1607. OS Build: 14393.2368

Comment: Any AV (anti-virus) difference between two of them or use `docker info` and verify that you data-root is in the same location

Comment: Yes its data root same on both machines C:\ProgramData\docker. Both machines have SEP.

Comment: Try to fiddle with SEP and make sure it's on supported version (only certain versions of SEP work with windows containers). Compare output of `fltmc` on both machines. The last thing to try `auditpol /clear`, reboot bad machine and try again

Comment: Both M1 and M2 got same SEP version. 
Also, docker root folder is in SEP's exceptions list on both M1 and M2.

Comment: What version of SEP is it?

Comment: 12.1.6 (12.1 RU6 MP8) build 7266 (12.1.7266.6800)

Comment: This version does not support Windows containers (does not matter if it runs on one and not another).

Comment: Ah! Do you have any link or doc which specifies the approved and supported list?

Comment: https://support.symantec.com/en_US/article.TECH236867.html

Comment: Thanks for all your help and info. Very useful.